# Unable to get itemclick fired in ext.js

Tags: extjs

I am unable to fire itemclick event on a cellclick in  ext.js [4.1..1a GPL]. My app.js goes like :

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
 var k =  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Tic Tac Toe',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
    layout: {
            type: 'table',
            // The total column count must be specified here
            columns: 3
        },
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle:'padding:20px'
        }
    ,
        items: [{
            html: '',
        },{
            html: '',
        },{
            html: ''
        },{
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners :
    {
        itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
           alert(record);
       }
    }
   });
}
});
```

Anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This listener does not exist for a panel. You will need at least a view. The example below catches the click event for each of your 'fields'.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
 var k =  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Tic Tac Toe',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
    layout: {
            type: 'table',
            // The total column count must be specified here
            columns: 3
        },
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle:'padding:20px',
            listeners: {
                afterRender: function(p) {
                    p.body.on('click', function() { alert(p.id) });
                }
            }
        }
    ,
        items: [{
            html: ''
        },{
            html: '',
        },{
            html: ''
        },{
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
    {
            html: ''
        },
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });
}
});
```

Comment: however SRA what remains here is how do I get the text which is placed inside each panel , e.g. how do I get value  which is inside  html: ''

Comment: @Satya html is sort of static property and get deleted after the component has been rendered. So You will have to work on the dom to receive the value but can use update to set a new. Just change the event callback body to `p.body.on('click', function() { p.update('B'); alert(p.getTargetEl().dom.innerHTML); });` This will update and fetch the new value value.